# Concluding that local $SU(2)$ symmetry implies that we have charged and uncharged fields

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, gauge-theory, yang-mills, electroweak

In Samoil Bilenky's (2nd. ed) "Introduction to the Physics of Massive and Mixed Neutrinos," he constructs the $SU(2)$ Yang-Mills model.

He starts by introducing the doublet (section 3.2, page 36):
$$\psi (x)=\begin{pmatrix}  \psi ^{(+1)} \\  \psi ^{(-1)} \\  \end{pmatrix}  \tag{Eq. 1} $$

Here's where the confusion starts: He doesn't say anything about what this doublet represents physically except that both $\psi ^{(+1)}$ and $\psi ^{(-1)}$ are spin 1/2 fields (page 36).

From the global $SU(2)$, we can show that there are 3 conserved currents (one per generator, where the generators are the Pauli Matrices)
$$j_{i}^{\alpha }(x)=\overline{\psi }(x)\gamma ^{\alpha }\frac{1}{2}\sigma _i \psi (x)\tag{Eq. 2}$$
For $i=1,2,3$. He then explores the idea of local $SU(2)$ transformations, where we introduce the three gauge fields:
$$\mathbf{A}_{\mu }\equiv (A^1 _{\mu }A^2 _{\mu },A^3 _{\mu })\tag{Eq. 3}$$
He then proposes the following combinations:
$$j_{\alpha }(x)=2 \left( j^1 _{\alpha }(x)+ij^2 _{\alpha }(x) \right) \tag{Eq. 4}$$
And
$$W_{\alpha }(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(A_{\alpha }^1 (x)-iA^2 _{\mu }(x))\tag{Eq. 5}$$
And it is clear that the "Interaction" lagrangian can be written as
$$\mathscr{L}_{\text{Interaction} }=-\mathbf{j}_{\alpha }(x)\cdot \mathbf{A}^{\alpha }(x)\tag{Eq. 6}$$
And as
$$\mathscr{L}_{\text{Interaction} }= \left( -\frac{g}{2\sqrt{2}}j_{\alpha }(x)W^{\alpha }(x)+\text{h.c.}  \right) -gj_{\alpha }^3 (x)A^{\alpha 3}(x)\tag{Eq. 7}$$
Given the form of the Doublet (Eq. 1), we can show that $j_{\alpha }$ is really:
$$j_{\alpha }(x)=2\overline{\psi }^{(+1)}(x)\gamma _{\alpha }\psi ^{(-1)}(x)\tag{Eq. 8}$$
And now I include a screenshot of the lines of text that follow in the book:

[image]

I can't seem to understand why he concludes that the $W^{\alpha }$ is a field with vector particles with electric charge $\pm 1$. Furthermore, all this discussion happens way before talking about the Electroweak interaction. Why is he using hypercharge and electric charge at this point? Clearly, there should be a way to interpret this without throwing physical concepts for now, isn't there?

In light of this, is there anything we can say about the $(\pm 1)$ labels on the fields inside the doublet?

Bilenky then proceeds to use a similar argument to show that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that book, and I certainly would not read it with you annotating his highly nonstandard formalism and language. In any case, think of $(\psi^{(+)}, \psi^{(+)})^T$ as $(\nu, e)^T$ or $(u,d)^T$, etc... in your eqn (1).

Your (3.33) then reads as
$$
j_\alpha= 2 \bar u \gamma_\alpha d, 
$$
whose charge destroys a *d* to create a *u*, so raises the charge by 1.

Consequently, the *W* coupling to it in (7) must lower the charge by one, by destroying a $W^+$ in common parlance, since (7) must conserve charge, which it does in all three of its terms.

Likewise, (3.35) presents as
$$
j_\alpha^3= \tfrac{1}{2} ( \bar u \gamma_\alpha u -  \bar d \gamma_\alpha d  ) 
$$
preserving charge, since it creates the quarks it destroys, with funny phases; consequently, by the same argument, $A^3_\alpha$ must be neutral as well. It is the weak-isospin partner of the two Ws.

You could replicate these points for leptons,  $(\nu, e)^T$, instead of quarks, just outlined.

Admittedly, the language is so eccentric, one wonders why you don't pick a more mainstream tasteful text.